# cpanel php class not creating object

Tags: php, cpanel, live

We used "cPanel API2" library to create park domain in our server and it was working fine until last cPanel up-gradation.

We created file mytest.live.php on server to create a object of "CPANEL class" for troubleshooting the issue, but unfortunately it returns error as below.

```
<?php
 require_once "/usr/local/cpanel/php/cpanel.php";
 $cpanel = new CPANEL(); ?>
```

And Output Returns:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'There     was a problem fetching the env variablecontaining the path to the socket' in /usr/local/cpanel/php/cpanel.php:146 Stack trace: #0 /home/cityusa/public_html/mytest.live.php(4): CPANEL->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in /usr/local/cpanel/php/cpanel.php on line 146
```

So please help for resolve this issue.

Comment: PHP applications that use the LiveAPI PHP class must instantiate the CPANEL object.
PHP filenames must end in either the .livephp or .live.php file extensions. 
Save files to the /usr/local/base/frontend/theme/ directory, where theme is the cPanel theme, or create a symlink to the appropriate files.

Comment: above things you need to check

Comment: $cpanel = new CPANEL();
instead of
$cpanel = new CPANEL;

Comment: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+the+LiveAPI+System+-+PHP+Class

Answer (score 0):

You should try naming your file as "*.live.php" or "*.livephp". That worked for me.